# Check summability of a function ($L^1$)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I have this function and I have to prove that is't $ L ^1 (\mathbb R^+) $:
$$ f(x)=\frac{1-cos(x)}{x^{3/2}} , x\in \mathbb R^+ $$

That's what I did:

1) first I tried to check the $\infty$ problem:
$$ |f(x)| \le \frac{2}{|x^{3/2}|}  $$
when $x \rightarrow \infty$ the function is infinitesimal of order 3/2 which is greater than 1, so for comparison with 1/x the $ \infty $ should be ok for me;

2) after that I tried to consider the problem in $x=0$ having that:
$$ |f(x)| \sim \frac{x^2}{x^{3/2}} = x^{1/2} $$
when $ x \rightarrow 0$ the function is infinitesimal of order 1/2 which is lower than 1, so for comparison with 1/x, $x=0$ is giving a real problem, making the function being not summable.

Unluckily the test is telling me that $f(x)$ is summable. What's wrong with my method?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ has no integrability issue in a right neighbourhood of the origin. It is a continuous function over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank, so the infinitesimal order have to be greater than 1 only when the $x^\alpha$ is at the denominator. Except for that, is this method to check the summability correct?